# VS 2010 Default Class Template for Windows Phone 7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Hi I've created a new WP7 project. Then I add a new project of type Windows Phone Class Library and by default the project has System.Net, System.Windows and System.Xml references beside other references. I don't need them in my Class Library so I delete them but when I create a new class Visual Studio create the following class :

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WP7
{
    public class Class1
    {

    }
}
```

but I've already removed the references System.Net & System.Windows. I'm getting an error when I try to compile the solution.
How I can modify the default template ?
I want to be something like

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WP7
{
    public class Class1
    {

    }
}
```

I think this is a bug in VS2010. It doesn't respect the the current references of the project when adding a new class. How can I report this bug to MS ?

Answer (score 0):

this is just how item templates and project templates work. You could create your own set, but that just isn't going to be quick and easy.

The idea is that these assemblies are needed in the majority of apps.

Since they are present on the device and not packaged into your .XAP, there is no net effect to your app.